# How can i loop each item of list in each column?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

List item data looping but i have failed looping each list item of individual col-md-4.But list item loops through only one col-md-4,I want each item of list show in each col.Please suggest me

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let countries = [
      { name: "Bangladesh", capital: "Dhaka" },
      { name: "Belgium", capital: "Brussels" },
      { name: "France", capital: "Paris" },
      { name: "Greece", capital: "Athens" }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="App">

            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <ul>
                  {countries.map(country => (
                    <li>
                      Capital of {country.name} is {country.capital};
                   </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let countries = [
      { name: "Bangladesh", capital: "Dhaka" },
      { name: "Belgium", capital: "Brussels" },
      { name: "France", capital: "Paris" },
      { name: "Greece", capital: "Athens" }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="App">

            <div className="row">
              {countries.map(country => (<div className="col-md-4">
                <ul>
                  
                    <li>
                      Capital of {country.name} is {country.capital};
                   </li>
                 
                </ul>
              </div> ))}

            </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mosè Raguzzini